# Payment platform that takes in two types of cards and checks for authorization and pin verification

Tags: c++

This is a payment platform that takes in two types of cards and checks for authorization and pin verification.

I'm particularly interested in finding any semantic/logical errors I've overlooked.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
enum class CardType {
    PISA,
    BlasterCard,
};
class Card {
public:
    const std::string card_number;

    explicit Card(const char* card_number) : card_number(card_number), is_active(true) {}

    bool is_card_active() const {
        return is_active;
    }
    void disable_card() {
        is_active = false;
    }
    void update_transaction_counter() {
        tx_counter += 1;
    }
    virtual bool is_pin_required() const = 0;
protected:
    int tx_counter;
    bool is_active;
};
class PisaCard : public Card {

public:
    using Card::Card;
    bool is_pin_required() const final {
        return tx_counter % 4 == 0;
    }
};
class BlasterCard: public Card {

public:
    using Card::Card;
    bool is_pin_required() const final {
        return tx_counter % 2 == 0;
    }
};
class CardNetwork {
public:
    struct CardNetworkCardData{
        std::string card_number;
        std::string pin;
        float balance;
    };
    void add_card(CardNetworkCardData new_card) {
        cards.push_back(new_card);
    }
    enum class TransactionOutcome {
        Approved,
        InsufficientFunds,
        WrongPin,
        InvalidCard,
        Unknown,
    };
    virtual TransactionOutcome perform_transaction(std::string card_number, std::string pin, float amount) {
        auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(cards), std::end(cards), [&card_number](const auto& card_data) {
            return card_number.c_str() == card_data.card_number;
        });
        if (it == std::end(cards)) {
            return TransactionOutcome::InvalidCard;
        }
        if (it->pin.c_str() != pin.c_str()) {
            return TransactionOutcome::WrongPin;
        }
        if (it->balance < amount) {
            return TransactionOutcome::InsufficientFunds;
        }
        return TransactionOutcome::Approved;

    }
private:
    std::vector<CardNetworkCardData> cards;
};
class Person {
public:
    struct PersonCardData{
        Card* card_ptr;
        std::string pin;
    };
    void add_card(PersonCardData new_card) {
        cards.push_back(new_card);
    }
    Card* find_available_card(CardType type) {
        for(auto& card : cards) {
            switch(type) {
                case CardType::BlasterCard:
                    if (dynamic_cast<BlasterCard*>(card.card_ptr)) {
                        return card.card_ptr;
                    } break;
                case CardType::PISA:
                    if (dynamic_cast<PisaCard*>(card.card_ptr)) {
                        return card.card_ptr;
                    } break;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::string get_pin_for_card(Card* card_ptr) {
        for (size_t t = 0; t <= cards.size(); ++t) {
            if (card_ptr == cards[t].card_ptr) {
                return cards[t].pin;
            }
        }
        return {};
    }
private:
    std::vector<PersonCardData> cards;
};
namespace {
    CardNetwork PISA_CARD_NETWORK{};
    CardNetwork BLASTERCARD_NETWORK{};
}
class PaymentTerminal {
public:
    PaymentTerminal(std::vector<CardType> supported_card_types) : supported_card_types(supported_card_types) {}
    std::function<void()> perform_transaction(Person& person, float amount) {
        Card* card_ptr = nullptr;
        for(auto supported_card_type : supported_card_types) {
            card_ptr = person.find_available_card(supported_card_type);
            if (!card_ptr) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        std::string pin{};
        if (card_ptr->is_pin_required()) {
            pin = person.get_pin_for_card(card_ptr);
        }
        CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome outcome = CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::Unknown;
        if (dynamic_cast<PisaCard*>(card_ptr)) {
            outcome = PISA_CARD_NETWORK.perform_transaction(card_ptr->card_number, pin, amount);
        }
        if (dynamic_cast<BlasterCard*>(card_ptr)) {
            outcome = BLASTERCARD_NETWORK.perform_transaction(card_ptr->card_number, pin, amount);
        }
        switch(outcome) {
            case CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::Approved:{
                return [&card_ptr]() {
                    card_ptr->update_transaction_counter();
                    std::printf("Transaction Approved\n");
                };
                case CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::InvalidCard:{
                    return [&card_ptr]() {
                        card_ptr->update_transaction_counter();

                        card_ptr->disable_card();
                        std::printf("This is not a valid card, blocking.\n");
                    };
                }
                case CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::InsufficientFunds:{
                    return [&card_ptr]() {
                        card_ptr->update_transaction_counter();

                        std::printf("You have insufficient balance.\n");
                    };
                }
                case CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::WrongPin: {
                    return [&card_ptr]() {
                        card_ptr->update_transaction_counter();

                        std::printf("Wrong PIN\n");
                    };
                }
                case CardNetwork::TransactionOutcome::Unknown: {
                    return []() {
                        std::printf("Unknown failure reason\n");
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<CardType> supported_card_types;
};
int main() {
    PISA_CARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"431267238214", "1013", 10.0f});
    PISA_CARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"438512582395", "5235", 100.0f});
    PISA_CARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"439571420023", "0000", 0.0f});
    BLASTERCARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"642302359023", "1111", 1000.0f});
    BLASTERCARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"649045468723", "2453", 100.0f});
    BLASTERCARD_NETWORK.add_card(CardNetwork::CardNetworkCardData{"640912058240", "8230", 23.0f});
    PaymentTerminal terminal_one{{CardType::BlasterCard}};
    PaymentTerminal terminal_two{{CardType::PISA}};
    PaymentTerminal terminal_thr{{CardType::PISA, CardType::BlasterCard}};
    Person person_one;
    person_one.add_card(Person::PersonCardData{new PisaCard{"431267238214"}, "1013"});
    person_one.add_card(Person::PersonCardData{new BlasterCard{"642302359023"}, "1011"});
    Person person_two;
    person_two.add_card(Person::PersonCardData{new PisaCard{"444233314202"}, "1010"});
    terminal_one.perform_transaction(person_one, 1.0f)();
    terminal_one.perform_transaction(person_two, 100.0f)();
    terminal_two.perform_transaction(person_two, 10.0f)();
    terminal_two.perform_transaction(person_one, 1.0f)();
    terminal_thr.perform_transaction(person_one, 5.0f)();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, our goal here is to help you improve your code by making insightful observations about the code that is written. The code must be working as intended already. Please indicate if the code is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Things nice to see: `enum class`, `explicit` conversion constructor, `const` member functions, library data types for managing resources of classes.

---

`cstdlib` is unused and redundant.

---

The variable `tx_counter` is left uninitialized. It should be initialized in declaration. The same applies to `is_active` because the conversion constructor has a single `card_number` parameter. E.g.,

```
class Card
{
public:
    explicit Card(const char* card_number) : card_number(card_number) { }
//...
protected:
    int tx_counter = 0;
    bool is_active = false;
};
```

If C++17 is an option, consider replacing `const char*` with `std::string_view` to allow `std::string` arguments.

---

For class design consistency, make the `card_number` member non-public.

---

There is no need to repeat entity name in names of class member functions, e.g. write `is_active` and `disable` instead of `is_card_active` and `disable_card`.

---

Declaring the `is_pin_required` method implies the presence of the `pin` attribute, which is absent in `Card`.
Is pin a card property?
We also miss `override` in subclasses

```
bool is_pin_required() const final override
```

---

We [probably need](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c127-a-class-with-a-virtual-function-should-have-a-virtual-or-protected-destructor) a virtual destructor `~Card()`.

---

`++tx_counter` is equivalent to `tx_counter += 1`

---

It is [perhaps a bad idea](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c133-avoid-protected-data) to declare `protected` class members because they resemble global variables in class scope.
After all, there are publicly inherited public getters and setters.

---

It is unclear whether we are allowed to copy or move class data.
For instance, can we have a duplicate `Card` object with a different amount of transactions?

---

Since we already have `CardType` identifiers, we could use them to identify object types instead of applying `dynamic_cast`.

```
class Card
{
public:
    virtual CardType type() const = 0;
};

class PisaCard : public Card
{
public:
    CardType type() const override {
        return CardType::PISA;
    }

    void pisa() const {
        std::cout << "I am pisa\n";
    }
};

class BlasterCard : public Card
{
public:
    CardType type() const override {
        return CardType::BlasterCard;
    }

    void blaster() const {
        std::cout << "I am blaster\n";
    }
};

PisaCard pc;
BlasterCard bc;
std::vector<Card*> v = { &pc, &bc };
auto it = find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](Card* p) { return p->type() == CardType::PISA; });
if (it != std::end(v)) {
    static_cast<PisaCard*>(*it)->pisa();
}
```

I would try to rethink the solution in a way to avoid applying both approaches.
Note how inappropriate does the `switch` operator look in the loop in `find_available_card`.

---

An integrated floating type must not be used to store `balance` due to known rounding errors.
There is an infinite number of perfectly fine rational numbers that can't be represented with integrated floating types.

Storing pins as plain text is also a bad practice.

---

Passing raw pointers raises the question of resource ownership.
Consider returning a reference from `find_available_card`.

---

There is an array bounds overrun in `get_pin_for_card`, which is an undefined behavior.

---

The function `perform_transaction` should finalize the transaction, not return a finalization procedure.
What we basically have

```
auto finalize = terminal_one.perform_transaction(person_one, 1.0f);
finalize();
```

---

All the lambdas returned from `perform_transaction` have invalid references to the local variable `card_ptr`.
We must capture the variable by value, `[card_ptr](){}`.